# kubernetes.io/csi: expected valid fsGroupPolicy, received nil value or empty string

Tags: kubernetes, storage

I have a problem with storage in Kubernetes. I run a Kubernetes cluster with one master and two worker nodes at Hetzner Online
EDIT - It is installed with kubeadm and runs flannel as cni provider.

Now I try to create pods with volumes for persistence (later I want to run a Kafka in the cluster). Hetzner offers a storageclass with csi provider. This always creates storage at Hetzner for a pvc and integrates this into the server. This also works so far. But when I add a PVC and a pod to debug the storage everything is created as expected but the volume can't be mounted.

Debug yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: debug-pvc
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
---
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: volume-debugger
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: volume-to-debug
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: debug-pvc
  containers:
    - name: debugger
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/data"
          name: volume-to-debug
```

Description of the pod:

```
Name:         volume-debugger
Namespace:    kafka
Priority:     0
Node:         jm-website-worker-02/10.98.0.4
Start Time:   Tue, 09 Mar 2021 12:51:57 +0100
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Pending
IP:
IPs:          <none>
Containers:
  debugger:
    Container ID:
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /data from volume-to-debug (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-nb969 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  volume-to-debug:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  debug-pvc
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-nb969:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-nb969
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age               From                           Message
  ----     ------                  ----              ----                           -------
  Normal   Scheduled               19s                                              Successfully assigned kafka/volume-debugger to jm-website-worker-02
  Normal   SuccessfulAttachVolume  14s               attachdetach-controller        AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-e5a3b3ed-f4d8-4cb7-850e-ceb31cc71eca"
  Warning  FailedMount             4s (x5 over 12s)  kubelet, jm-website-worker-02  MountVolume.NewMounter initialization failed for volume "pvc-e5a3b3ed-f4d8-4cb7-850e-ceb31cc71eca" : kubernetes.io/csi: expected valid fsGroupPolicy, received nil value or empty string
```

Descrition of the pvc:

```
Name:          debug-pvc
Namespace:     kafka
StorageClass:  hcloud-volumes
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-e5a3b3ed-f4d8-4cb7-850e-ceb31cc71eca
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: csi.hetzner.cloud
               volume.kubernetes.io/selected-node: jm-website-worker-02
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      10Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    volume-debugger
Events:
  Type    Reason                 Age    From                                                                            Message
  ----    ------                 ----   ----                                                                            -------
  Normal  WaitForFirstConsumer   4m46s  persistentvolume-controller                                                     waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning   4m46s  persistentvolume-controller                                                     waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "csi.hetzner.cloud" or manually created by system administrator
  Normal  Provisioning           4m46s  csi.hetzner.cloud_hcloud-csi-controller-0_5e46eb4e-346a-4772-ac3b-048524a37eec  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "kafka/debug-pvc"
  Normal  ProvisioningSucceeded  4m42s  csi.hetzner.cloud_hcloud-csi-controller-0_5e46eb4e-346a-4772-ac3b-048524a37eec  Successfully provisioned volume pvc-e5a3b3ed-f4d8-4cb7-850e-ceb31cc71eca
```

and the description of the pv itself:

```
Name:              pvc-e5a3b3ed-f4d8-4cb7-850e-ceb31cc71eca
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: csi.hetzner.cloud
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection external-attacher/csi-hetzner-cloud]
StorageClass:      hcloud-volumes
Status:            Bound
Claim:             kafka/debug-pvc
Reclaim Policy:    Delete
Access Modes:      RWO
VolumeMode:        Filesystem
Capacity:          10Gi
Node Affinity:
  Required Terms:
    Term 0:        csi.hetzner.cloud/location in [nbg1]
Message:
Source:
    Type:              CSI (a Container Storage Interface (CSI) volume source)
    Driver:            csi.hetzner.cloud
    FSType:            ext4
    VolumeHandle:      9907113
    ReadOnly:          false
    VolumeAttributes:      storage.kubernetes.io/csiProvisionerIdentity=1615290679845-8081-csi.hetzner.cloud
Events:                <none>
```

I'm using Kubernetes version 1.20.4. And the [Hetzner CSI](https://github.com/hetznercloud/csi-driver) in version master for K8s v1.20. I tried to fix this problem for a week now but I can't find anything helpful. I tried something with PodSecurity policies and security context already but it doesn't work out the right way.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How did you install Kubernetes ?
Did you use `kubeadm` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There was an error with updating the master node. After reinstalling the master everything worked as expected.